# Editing behavior of "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save"

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, preference

In the `Preferences.sublime-settings` file, a particular attribute called `ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save` exists and I'd like to only activate it for non-minified files. It'd be nice to pass it a regular expression like `/min\.[^\.]+$/` to make it omit these files but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is the contents of the `trim_trailing_white_space.py` file under the Default packages folder:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class TrimTrailingWhiteSpace(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        if view.settings().get("trim_trailing_white_space_on_save") == True:
            trailing_white_space = view.find_all("[\t ]+$")
            trailing_white_space.reverse()
            edit = view.begin_edit()
            for r in trailing_white_space:
                view.erase(edit, r)
            view.end_edit(edit)

class EnsureNewlineAtEof(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        if view.settings().get("ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save") == True:
            if view.size() > 0 and view.substr(view.size() - 1) != '\n':
                edit = view.begin_edit()
                view.insert(edit, view.size(), "\n")
                view.end_edit(edit)
```

I have changed the second class to this implementation:

```
class EnsureNewlineAtEof(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        if view.settings().get("ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save") == True:
            if ".min." not in view.name():
                if view.size() > 0 and view.substr(view.size() - 1) != '\n':
                    edit = view.begin_edit()
                    view.insert(edit, view.size(), "\n")
                    view.end_edit(edit)
```

But it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty straightforward to do, and you don't even need regex to do it. Select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open up Sublime's `Packages` folder in your operating system's file manager. Go into the `Default` folder and open `trim_trailing_white_space.py` in Sublime. Line 15 starts the third class definition in the file:

```py
class EnsureNewlineAtEofCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if self.view.size() > 0 and self.view.substr(self.view.size() - 1) != '\n':
            self.view.insert(edit, self.view.size(), "\n")
```

Delete the entire class (all four lines), then paste in the following:

```py
class EnsureNewlineAtEofCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if ".min." not in self.view.name():
            if self.view.size() > 0 and self.view.substr(self.view.size() - 1) != '\n':
                self.view.insert(edit, self.view.size(), "\n")
```

What I did was add a test to see if the view's filename contains `.min.` (as in `foobar.min.js` or `bottom.div.min.css`, for example). If the filename *does* contain the pattern, nothing happens. If it *doesn't*, then a newline is added like normal.

Save the file (**do not** change the filename!), and restart Sublime for the changes to take effect.

---

Please note that the above instructions are for Sublime Text 2. ST3 does not have its packages directly available, so you'll need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control, select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` from the Command Palette, then select `Default` and `trim_trailing_white_space.py`. Edit the file as above and save it, and the changes should take effect immediately, although you may wish to restart Sublime just for fun.

Comment: Thank you so much, this saves a lot of frustration when making a minor edit to a minified file!

Comment: Considering I haven't had time until now to test it, I was waiting to confirm it worked until I did so. I am well aware of how reputation works on this site.

Comment: And I have just tested your suggestion, it does not work. Please review my edit to revise your answer accordingly.

Comment: I checked the Sublime Text 2 docs and it says to use `view.file_name()` not `view.name()` so just add that to your answer when you get the chance.